# Connecting Web part to external Database

Tags: 2007, web-part, database

I'm trying to connect a **web-part** running in SharePoint 2007 site to an external Sql Server 2005 database. I get a `System.Secutity.SecurityException` with "**Request Failed**" message when I attach debugger to debug my web part.

Here's my present situation

1. Webpart dll is deployed in bin of web application
2. I have set **Trust Level** to **Full** in web.config
3. The application pool under which the sharepoint site is running is administrator on the server
4. Here's the connection string
   `@"Data Source=VISHAL_vm\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=LicensingDB;Integrated Security=True"`

This exception is thrown on `Connection.Open()` method

Comment: If this answer helped you, could you please mark it as the answer?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to have Kerberos configured for your SharePoint Farm and utilize SPN's on ActiveDirectory to enable that pass-through authentication.